# How can I create this table format?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to create this table format in `LaTeX`.

[image]

Can anybody help me to create this table?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{4-6}
                  &                   &                   &       &       &       &                   \\ \hline
                  &                   &                   &       &       &       &                   \\ \hline
                  &                   &                   &       &       &       &                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the table with some entries

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf Z} & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf X} & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf V} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf A} & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf Y} \\ \cline{4-6}
                   &                        &                        &    B     &    C   &    D   &                        \\ \hline
                   &                        &                        &          &        &        &                        \\ \hline
                   &                        &                        &          &        &        &                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Cragfelt, How can I write field names in this table..

Comment: @SaqibQamar Do you mean the entries in the cells of the table?

Comment: I have edited attached image with fields name, how can I write it..

Comment: @SaqibQamar Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.